# what is the difference between MASTER / SUB REQUEST in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

so im reading the internals documentation for symfony2 http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html and i dont understand this section http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/internals.html#events.

so, i want to know the difference between MASTER / SUB REQUEST ?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The master request is the one that comes from the original user; the subrequest is the one that you do internally — either with the [`forward()`](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/HttpKernel.html#method_forward) method of `HttpKernel` — or by the [`forward()`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#forwarding) helper of the framework's `Controller` class — or [`{% render ... %}`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers) in Twig.

Comment: Added links to the documentation sections.

Answer (score 6):

The master request is the one, that is triggered by the browser and the sub requests are requests from within the application. For example a template can render another action

```
<div id="sidebar">
    {% render "AcmeArticleBundle:Article:recentArticles" with {'max': 3} %}
</div>
```

(Example taken from [the manual](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers))

This will lead to a sub request.