# Does Symfony2 give wrong impression for requests (master and sub) or I get it wrong

Tags: php, symfony

When a user hits submit button in a webform (for instance, to insert data into database) event listener treats it as **Master** POST request whcih is fine. After successfull submission (data inserted into db), the logic `return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));` we have written in controller redirects user to success or fail page and this is also treated as **Master** GET request. Is it not supposed to be **Sub** GET request instead because user doesn't directly cause it?

Either I get whole stuff wrong or the answers ([what is the difference between MASTER / SUB REQUEST in Symfony2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456949/what-is-the-difference-between-master-sub-request-in-symfony2)) here are short/wrong.

And full [Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html) is here.

The reason I'm asking is I want to avoid allocating system resources when `redirect` happens.

**SERVICE**:

```
services:
    kernel.listener.kernel_request:
        class: Site\MainBundle\EventListener\Request\KernelRequest
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.request, method: onKernelRequest }
```

**EVENT LISTENER CLASS**:

```
<?php

namespace Site\MainBundle\EventListener\Request;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent;

class KernelRequest
{
    public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($event->isMasterRequest() === true) {
            // Do something with Master request
        } else {
            // Do something with sub request
        }
    }
}
```

**CIONTROLLER**:

```
publich function saveAction()
{
    // Insert user's POST stuff into database
    // Then either redirect to success or fail page like;
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('success-or-fail-page'));
}
```

Comment: `redirect` causes an HTTP redirect, which means the *user's browser* requests the new page. It's not a fake request instantiated by the framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect returns a redirect response with `302` status by default and that's it. Finito. Kernel shuts down.

Then User's browser get's redirected to your `success-or-fail-page` and you're receiving another regular master request, as you would if User just came to that page directly.

If you in fact want to issue a subrequest you should then do:

```
publich function saveAction()
{
    return $this->forward('YourBundle:YourController:action', ['params' => 'here']);
}
```

Comment: +1 - This solves my problem since forward() triggers sub request compared to redirect(). Thanks