# RequestStack when should I use getMasterRequest rather than getCurrentRequest?

Tags: php, http, symfony

Since [2.4](http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-4-the-request-stack), we can inject the `RequestStack` in our services.

To retrieve the current `Request`, there is two methods:

```
/** @var Request */
$request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

// OR

/** @var Request */
$request = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();
```

When should we use the `currentRequest` ?
And when should we use the `masterRequest`?

For example, if I need to retrieve the parameters in the body of the current `Request`, I would use:

```
$params = $request->request->all();
```

Which of the two methods should I use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When dealing with multiple requests, the non master request comes from internal requests. Usually from twig in the form of

```
{{ render(controller('foo')) }}
```

When the second request is created, only the request format and locale are copied to the new instance. Therefore, any data you would expect to come from the user, will not be available. This includes request parameters, ip address, and any HTTP headers.

In most situation, you will only need to deal with the current request. But, to answer your question, any time you need data coming from the user, you will require the master request. An example would be using the users IP address to pre-select a `CountryType` form control.

When using `getMasterRequest()->getClientIp()` you would be given the IP address of the user (something like 209.58.130.174). When calling it on the non master you will be given the localhost/loopback IP (127.0.0.1). There aren't really any methods that will return `null`, they simply return different information about how the request was created.

Comment: Pretty much all I needed, thank you. About the availability of user informations, can you please give me an example of a method that will not be accessible (or give an empty result) using the `currentRequest`, and be accessible using  the `masterRequest` ?

Answer (score 2):

> The master request is the one that comes from the original user; the subrequest is the one that you do internally — either with the forward() method of HttpKernel — or by the forward() helper of the framework's Controller class — or {% render ... %} in Twig.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12456998/1078488

This means you would normally use the current request, if you don't explicitely want the actual request made by the user.

I've used a service for injecting the current request:

```
app.request:
    class: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack
    factory:
        - '@request_stack'
        - 'getCurrentRequest'
```

Then you can inject it like this:

```
app.some_service:
    class: AppBundle\Service\SomeService
    arguments:
        - '@app.request'
        - '@some_other_service'
```

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I already saw the question you given, but I can't see when should I use the `masterRequest` rather than the `currentRequest`, and what would we the difference if I use the first or the second in order to retrieve informations from the request such as body parameters or headers. Is there a right way between these two possibilities?

Comment: That was the reason I answered instead of just voting to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Can you try to answer the questions I given in my previous comment ? And thanks for the factory, it's useful.

Comment: I already have. If it's not sufficient please comment on what's still unclear - or perhaps someone else will post a better answer.

Comment: Why use a factory and not just inject using the expression language? `"@=service('request_stack').getMasterRequest()"`

Comment: @Twifty no spesific reason

Comment: I wasn't able to see the impact of use the `master` rather than the `current`, which informations I will get using the `master` that I will not using the `current` (or inverse), @Twifty examples are sufficient. Thank's for your explanation and the factory that give me some good ideas.