# PHP recover complete URL drupal 8

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8

I work on a Drupal 8 site. In a page I have a PHP block who contain a form with GET method.

In the page who receive informations I have an URL who looks like `site/page?param1=value1&param2=value2`. I need to get **value2**.

I tried so many solutions but I don't find the solution :

```
$_GET['id'];
// returns : null

\Drupal::service('path.current')->getPath();
// returns : '/node/4'

$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
// returns : 'site/page'

$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
// returns : 'site/page'

$_SERVER['argv'];
// returns : null

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
// returns : 'http://site/node/4/edit'

\Drupal::request()->query->all();
// returns : array (size=0) empty

$path = \Drupal::request()->getpathInfo();
// returns : '/page'

\Drupal::request()->getRequestUri();
// returns : 'site/page'

\Drupal::request()->attributes->get('_system_path');
// returns : null

\Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')->getAliasByPath($current_path);
// returns : '/page'

$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// returns : ''

\Drupal::destination()->getAsArray();
// returns : 'site/page'
```

Can someone help me to find this **value2** which is in the URL ?

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve URL parameter(s) using multiple services such:

- request_stack
- path.current
- current_route_match

Here I show you how to get your `value2` from the `param2` using the `request_stack`:

```
// Initialize the service.
$requestStack = \Drupal::service('request_stack');

// Get your Master Request.
$masterRequest = $requestStack->getMasterRequest();

// Get the value from a GET parameter.
$value = $masterRequest->query->get('param2');
```

---

To go further:

- Don't use static call such `\Drupal::service('request_stack');` but you inject the service into you Block. See [this greate article about Dependency Injection in Drupal 8 Plugins](https://chromatichq.com/blog/dependency-injection-drupal-8-plugins).
- Understand the difference [between MasterRequest & SubRequest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12456949/what-is-the-difference-between-master-sub-request-in-symfony2).

---

Hope it will help you !

Comment: When I try this I got a "null". I think the problem is from the form and I will try to look at this. Thank you.

Comment: What is the real URL ? Could you please add your form code here also ? And the routing file (routing.yml) that powered your form.

Comment: You could also try using the `CurrentRequest` instead of the `MasterRequest`. Eg. `$request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();` If it works, you are in a SubRequest, checkout the link I gave you upper about Requests.

Answer (score 0):

```
$value = \Drupal::request()->query->get('param2');
```

Should do the trick.